# Milliseconds value in a .NET DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetimepicker

I assumed that if "fff" works in DateTime.ToString then it would work in the custom format string for a DateTimePicker, but it appears this is not the case.

I understand that there may not be an immediate solution, but this really isn't a critical problem, so what is a viable alternative?

A few ideas I had:

- Since the DateTimePicker onlyhas a pop down MonthCalender then I could use a DateTimePicker for the date and a masked textbox for the time, possibly with some simple event handling to make sure it's valid and acts a bit like a DateTimePicker.
- Add an extra NumericUpDown afterwards for milliseconds. Won't look great but I can restrict to 3 digits and it would work very easily.
- Do it properly and write a custom control that inherits DateTimePicker and does some clever stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a MaskedTextBox as it was quick and easy to put in the date/time format. I then added a simple button to the side which popped up a calendar in the same way that a DateTimePicker does.

Comment: You just saved a hell of time!

Answer (score 1):

There might be something available for free on the net:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Time_Picker.aspx

You are correct, the DateTimePicker does not natively support it so you need to choose one of your ideas.

Comment: I did have a look at that one when looking for solutions. In that case it is not a replacement for a DateTimePicker, and I'd probably write my own version if I went down the route of a custom textbox, as there would be a few extra things I'd get distracted and implement on the way.